# Server receiving webRequests long after removed from LoadBalancer

Tags: http, iis, webserver, load-balancing

*I had the following issue on a system that I supported ~7 years ago. We never got to the bottom of it, and focus shifted onto other issues. I was recently reminded of it, and wondered if anyone would know what was going on. But alas I'll be a little short on details. Sorry.*

---

**The Setup**

I had a farm of web servers sitting behind a load balancer. The servers were hosting a system that would receive HTTP requests (XML &/or SOAP) from clients, then for each one kick-off a bunch of further HTTP requests to 3rd-party-suppliers, wait for the suppliers' responses, process and combine the results and respond to the client's request.

Think insurance comparison, but as Business-To-Business XML service.

The whole processing would take 5s of seconds, from receiving the initial client request to them sending back a response to that original HTTP request, and the server would be processing 10s or 100s of requests in parallel (i.e. at any given point, a given webserver would have many client Requests that had come in, and been logged, but not yet been responded to.)

We had detailed logging which record the reciept of the requests, including origin IP and which server was processing the request, and record when a response was sent.

All client requests were sent to a single IP address (well, URL), which was the address of the loadbalancer, which would then forward requests to the webservers, which weren't individually accessible to the internet (they didn't have public IP addresses).

Our load balancer would allow us to take individual web-servers out of rotation, for maintenance.
When we did that we could watch the DB logs, and see new requests stop coming in, and the existing request gradually get completed, until there were now outstanding requests and the server was idle.

---

**The problem**

We found that sometimes, when we took a server out of rotation ... it wouldn't entirely stop receiving requests. You could see the large bulk of request suddenly stop coming in, but it would still receive a trickle of fresh requests (I don't know ... maybe 0.1% of normal load, maybe less?). I think the longest we left it going was maybe ... 10 minutes?

Notably we realised that all of those requests were coming from a single client/IP address (I don't remember which).
I forget whether other (still-in-rotation) webservers were still receiving requests from this client, but I *think* they were?

If we rebooted the webserver, no further requests would come in after restarting.

Web stack was Windows, IIS, ASP.NET; pretty old school even at the time. All servers individually owned and configured.

---

**What was happening?**

We vaguely waved our hands and asserted that the client's integration with us was "holding an HTTP tunnel open and sending multiple requests through it", rather than sending each request separately, and thus was maintaining that tunnel even after the LB stopped sending new requests to that server. But that was BS-waffle, and since we never needed to actually understand what was going on, we ignored it and moved on with our lives :)

But I'd still like to know what we were seeing, if anyone can diagnose it from that description.

Comment: Ideally an answer would give specifics about how the mechanism works, and how you would create and use such connection in C# (or search terms to find that detail myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We vaguely waved our hands and asserted that the client's integration with us was "holding an HTTP tunnel open and sending multiple requests through it", rather than sending each request separately, and thus was maintaining that tunnel even after the LB stopped sending new requests to that server.

That sounds like a good explanation.

Normally, a LB will refuse new connections to a removed server, but will allow open connections to live on until they naturally close. This is known as "connection draining" or "graceful shutdown".

If one of your clients had HTTP keepalive on, and was holding a TCP connection open and sending HTTP requests through it for a long time, it would give the symptoms you describe.

Most LBs will have a configuration knob for how long to wait for connections to close before force-closing them during this "connection draining" time. You can set a timeout here to avoid this scenario if it is a problem for you.

The HTTP connection handling behaviour of clients will vary at the client's discretion, to a large extent. Perhaps most of your clients were of one type (say, web browsers) and weren't holding open a single connection for 10 mins, but perhaps one client was different (say, a programmatic HTTP API client)?

Further reading about "connection draining" on AWS Load Balancers here (the exact details will vary by LB vendor): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html

Further reading about HTTP keep alive here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection